# Program doesn't output anything while there is a Timer and an ActionEvent, any ideas?

Tags: java, swing, timer, actionlistener, actionevent

This is supposed to print out the current time every second

```
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Timer1{
    final static int SPEED = 1000;
public static void main(String[] args){
    Timer t = new Timer(SPEED, new TimerListener());
    t.start();
}
}
```

---

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

class TimerListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    System.out.println(new Date()); 
}
}
```

The above are the 2 classes in my program

Comment: required to intialized the EDT, then same for SwingWorker etc...

Comment: What do you try to achieve? If you need just `Timer` use `java.util.Timer` or executors `ScheduledExecutorService newScheduledThreadPool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you do not see any output because the program terminates before the timer gets a chance. If you add a delay at the end, you will see date/time lines.

In the code, I have also added an example with the `java.util.Timer` that [alex2410](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2894369/alex2410) suggested:

```
public class TimerTest {
    private static final int SPEED = 1000;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new TimerTest().testTimers();
    }

    private void testTimers() {
        testSwingTimer();
        System.out.println("------");
        testUtilTimer();
    }

    private void testSwingTimer() {
        final javax.swing.Timer t =
            new javax.swing.Timer(SPEED, e -> System.out.println("testSwingTimer: "
                                                                 + new Date()));
        t.start();
        delay(4000);
    }

    private void testUtilTimer() {
        final TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("testUtilTimer: " + new Date());
            }
        };
        final java.util.Timer timer = new java.util.Timer(true);
        timer.schedule(task, 0, SPEED);
        delay(2000);
    }

    private void delay(final int milliseconds) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(milliseconds);
        } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @alex2410: could you clarify why `Thread.sleep` and Swing are a bad combination? Is it OK to use `Thread.sleep` and `java.util.Timer` together?

Comment: Read [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/), sleep block `EDT`.

Comment: @alex2410: in this case the `Thread.sleep(4000);` is not executed on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) but on the main thread, so I think the call to sleep will not block the GUI. But as you already mentioned and since there is no GUI (yet), it is probably better to use `java.util.Timer`.

Comment: It's very simple example with running timer from main, in another case it'll be edt.

Answer (score -1):

Ironically i just faced the same issue too , see below(just to illustrate the point ,may not always be suitable)

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TimerTest {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int time=2000;//10 sec
        Timer t1=new Timer(time, new TimerListener());
        t1.start();
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Click To stop Timer");
    }

}

class TimerListener implements ActionListener{

     private int count=5;
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Date d=new Date();
        System.out.println(d);
        Toolkit t=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        t.beep();

    }

    }
```

The issue is as mentioned by others ,the main method `starts` the `Timer` and immediately executes  the next line  of code and so on and exits eventually *before the Timer can fire* , so you need to keep main running , the example above does this by showing a GUI Dialog window , until you click on it the Timer event keeps on firing after every interval.

Alternatively if you want to run the application from a Terminal (terminal mode as in without GUI ,Eg:Linux Terminal Emulations etc) , another approach(rather bad ) is shown below.(I would recommend not using this )

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TimerTest {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int time=2000;//10 sec
        Timer t1=new Timer(time, new TimerListener());
        t1.start();

        while(true){

        }
    }

}

class TimerListener implements ActionListener{

     private int count=5;
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Date d=new Date();
        System.out.println(d);
        Toolkit t=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        t.beep();
        if(getCount()>0)
        {
            count--;
        }
        else
            System.out.printf("Done");

    }
    /**
     * @return the count
     */
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

}
```

Comment: `while(true){

        }` really bad idea

Comment: As i mentioned the OP wanted to know why it terminated without printing , so  i used the infinite loop to illustrate to him without obscuring the code with sleep or  SwingWorker or other mechanisms